# Control of \chemfig positioning within tabular

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, horizontal-alignment, chemfig

Implementation below seeks to center `\chemfig` objects horizontally within a center-aligned column of a tabular environment.

Getting unexpected results.  Please see commenting around the `\begin{tabular}`.  Suggests that `chemfig` objects are carrying around extra space?

```
\documentclass[border=6pt,active]{standalone}%
\usepackage{booktabs}%
\usepackage{miscchemsym}%
\usepackage{chemfig}%
\usepackage{filecontents}%
\usepackage{tikz}%
\usepackage{catchfile}%

% chemfigdo
\newcommand{\chemfigdo}[2]{\chemfig[#2]{#1}}%

% chemfiginput
\newcommand{\chemfiginput}[2][]{%
\CatchFileDef{\chemfiginputtemp}{#2}{\csname CF_sanitizecatcode\endcsname}%
\expandafter\chemfigdo\expandafter{\chemfiginputtemp}{#1}%
}%

% create new command for tikzpicture call
\newcommand\callchemfigsymbol[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,%
xscale=-1,%
yscale=-1,%
inner sep=0pt,%
outer sep=0pt,%
baseline=(current bounding box.center)]%
\chemfiginput[%
atom style={scale=\chemfigscale},%
atom sep=\chemfigatomsep,%
chemfig style={color=\chemfigcolor,line width=\chemfiglinewidth}%
]{#1}%
\end{tikzpicture}%
}%

% define the atom sep
\newlength{\chemfigatomsep}%
\setlength{\chemfigatomsep}{2.75em}%

% define the line width
\newlength{\chemfiglinewidth}%
\setlength{\chemfiglinewidth}{0.75pt}%

% define the scale
\def\chemfigscale{0.8}

% define the color
\def\chemfigcolor{red!40!black}

% define separation length
\setlength{\defaultaddspace}{13mm}



\begin{document}


\begin{filecontents}{methane_pseudo_3D_stereo.tex}
           H% 2
     -[:270]C% 1
              (
        -[:200]H% 4
              )
              (
         <[:310]H% 5
              )
    <:[:350]H% 3
\end{filecontents}


\begin{filecontents}{sulfurhexafluoride_pseudo_3D_stereo.tex}
           F% 1
     -[:90]S% 2
              (
        <[:337.5]F% 3
              )
              (
        <[:202.5]F% 4
              )
              (
         <:[:22.5]F% 5
              )
              (
         -[:90]F% 7
              )
    <:[:157.5]F% 6
\end{filecontents}%


\begin{filecontents}{trifluoromethylsulfurpentafluoride_pseudo_3D_stereo.tex}
F% 2
    -[:300]C% 1
              (
        -[:240]F% 3
              )
              (
        -[:180]F% 4
              )
          -S% 5
              (
        <[:240]F% 6
              )
              (
        <[:120]F% 7
              )
              (
        <:[:300]F% 8
              )
              (
              -F% 10
              )
     <:[:60]F% 9
\end{filecontents}%


\begin{tabular}[]{cc}
%\begin{tabular}[]{cp{4cm}}
\toprule
\textbf{Compound name} & \textbf{Structure} \\%
\midrule%
\\%
Methane & \callchemfigsymbol{methane_pseudo_3D_stereo.tex} \\%
[\defaultaddspace]%
%
Sulfurhexafluoride & \callchemfigsymbol{sulfurhexafluoride_pseudo_3D_stereo.tex} \\%
[\defaultaddspace]%
%
Trifluoromethyl-sulfurpentafluoride & \callchemfigsymbol{trifluoromethylsulfurpentafluoride_pseudo_3D_stereo.tex} \\%
\\%
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, the extra space mostly comes from the extra `\\` used in `tabular` and the large value set to `\defaultaddspace`, which is used as `\\[\defaultaddspace]` in `tabular`.

Secondly, the `\chemfiginput` already creates a `tikzpicture` environment, and it's not recommended (and generally not supported) to nest `tikzpicture`. You can pass desired `tikzpicture` environment options to `chemfig style={...}`.

Following is an example in which

- extra `\\` is removed and `\defaultaddspace` is set to appropreate value, and
- nested `tikzpicture` is removed (in definition of `\callchemfigsymbol`)

```
\documentclass[border=6pt,active]{standalone}%
\usepackage{booktabs}%
%\usepackage{miscchemsym}%
\usepackage{chemfig}%
\usepackage{filecontents}%
\usepackage{tikz}%
\usepackage{catchfile}%

% chemfigdo
\newcommand{\chemfigdo}[2]{\chemfig[#2]{#1}}%

% chemfiginput
\newcommand{\chemfiginput}[2][]{%
\CatchFileDef{\chemfiginputtemp}{#2}{\csname CF_sanitizecatcode\endcsname}%
\expandafter\chemfigdo\expandafter{\chemfiginputtemp}{#1}%
}%

% create new command for tikzpicture call
\newcommand\callchemfigsymbol[1]{%
  \chemfiginput[
      atom style={scale=\chemfigscale},
      atom sep=\chemfigatomsep,
      chemfig style={
        baseline=(current bounding box.center),
        color=\chemfigcolor,
        line width=\chemfiglinewidth
      }
    ]{#1}%
}

% define the atom sep
\newlength{\chemfigatomsep}%
\setlength{\chemfigatomsep}{2.75em}%

% define the line width
\newlength{\chemfiglinewidth}%
\setlength{\chemfiglinewidth}{0.75pt}%

% define the scale
\def\chemfigscale{0.8}

% define the color
\def\chemfigcolor{red!40!black}

% define separation length
\setlength{\defaultaddspace}{25pt}


\begin{document}


\begin{filecontents}{methane_pseudo_3D_stereo.tex}
           H% 2
     -[:270]C% 1
              (
        -[:200]H% 4
              )
              (
         <[:310]H% 5
              )
    <:[:350]H% 3
\end{filecontents}


\begin{filecontents}{sulfurhexafluoride_pseudo_3D_stereo.tex}
           F% 1
     -[:90]S% 2
              (
        <[:337.5]F% 3
              )
              (
        <[:202.5]F% 4
              )
              (
         <:[:22.5]F% 5
              )
              (
         -[:90]F% 7
              )
    <:[:157.5]F% 6
\end{filecontents}%


\begin{filecontents}{trifluoromethylsulfurpentafluoride_pseudo_3D_stereo.tex}
F% 2
    -[:300]C% 1
              (
        -[:240]F% 3
              )
              (
        -[:180]F% 4
              )
          -S% 5
              (
        <[:240]F% 6
              )
              (
        <[:120]F% 7
              )
              (
        <:[:300]F% 8
              )
              (
              -F% 10
              )
     <:[:60]F% 9
\end{filecontents}%


\begin{tabular}{cc}
  \toprule
  \textbf{Compound name} & \textbf{Structure} \\
  \midrule
  Methane & \callchemfigsymbol{methane_pseudo_3D_stereo.tex} \\[\defaultaddspace]
  Sulfurhexafluoride & \callchemfigsymbol{sulfurhexafluoride_pseudo_3D_stereo.tex} \\[\defaultaddspace]
  Trifluoromethyl-sulfurpentafluoride & \callchemfigsymbol{trifluoromethylsulfurpentafluoride_pseudo_3D_stereo.tex} \\[\defaultaddspace]
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Follow up:

Align every `\chemfiginput` at its center is not good enough. By default `chemfig` uses the base of first atom as the base of the entire molecule. Since OP's molecule code is the output of some program, which might be difficult to control which atom is the first, one can use `@{<node name>}` before any atom and use `chemfig style={baseline=(<node name>.base)}` to use the base of marked atom as that of the entire molecule.

Furthermore, in the following enhanced example a new `tikz` option `enlarge bounding box by` is provided in order to prohibit the `\\[\defaultaddspace]` and give more consistent vertical space.

This is nicer both in vertical alignment and in vertical space, isn't it?
[image]

```
\documentclass[border=6pt,active]{standalone}%
\usepackage{booktabs}%
%\usepackage{miscchemsym}%
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{catchfile}

% chemfigdo
\newcommand{\chemfigdo}[2]{\chemfig[#2]{#1}}

% chemfiginput
\newcommand{\chemfiginput}[2][]{%
  \CatchFileDef{\chemfiginputtemp}{#2}{\csname CF_sanitizecatcode\endcsname}%
  \expandafter\chemfigdo\expandafter{\chemfiginputtemp}{#1}%
}

\tikzset{
  % #1 = left, #2 = lower, #3 = right, #4 = upper
  enlarge bounding box by/.style n args={4}{
    execute at end picture={
      \path ([shift={(-#1, -#2)}]current bounding box.south west) --
            ([shift={(#3, #4)}]current bounding box.north east);
    }
  }
}

% create new command for tikzpicture call
\newcommand\callchemfigsymbol[2][current bounding box.center]{%
  \chemfiginput[
      atom style={scale=\chemfigscale},
      atom sep=\chemfigatomsep,
      chemfig style={
        enlarge bounding box by={0pt}{3pt}{0pt}{3pt},
        baseline=(#1),
        color=\chemfigcolor,
        line width=\chemfiglinewidth
      }
    ]{#2}%
}

% define the atom sep
\newlength{\chemfigatomsep}%
\setlength{\chemfigatomsep}{2.75em}%

% define the line width
\newlength{\chemfiglinewidth}%
\setlength{\chemfiglinewidth}{0.75pt}%

% define the scale
\def\chemfigscale{0.8}

% define the color
\def\chemfigcolor{red!40!black}

% define separation length
%\setlength{\defaultaddspace}{20pt}


\begin{document}


\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{methane_pseudo_3D_stereo.tex}
           H% 2
     -[:270]@{base}C% 1
              (
        -[:200]H% 4
              )
              (
         <[:310]H% 5
              )
    <:[:350]H% 3
\end{filecontents}


\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{sulfurhexafluoride_pseudo_3D_stereo.tex}
           F% 1
     -[:90]@{base}S% 2
              (
        <[:337.5]F% 3
              )
              (
        <[:202.5]F% 4
              )
              (
         <:[:22.5]F% 5
              )
              (
         -[:90]F% 7
              )
    <:[:157.5]F% 6
\end{filecontents}%


\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{trifluoromethylsulfurpentafluoride_pseudo_3D_stereo.tex}
F% 2
    -[:300]C% 1
              (
        -[:240]F% 3
              )
              (
        -[:180]@{base}F% 4
              )
          -S% 5
              (
        <[:240]F% 6
              )
              (
        <[:120]F% 7
              )
              (
        <:[:300]F% 8
              )
              (
              -F% 10
              )
     <:[:60]F% 9
\end{filecontents}%

\begin{tabular}{cc}
  \toprule
  \textbf{Compound name} & \textbf{Structure} \\
  \midrule
  Methane & \callchemfigsymbol[base.base]{methane_pseudo_3D_stereo.tex} \\
  Sulfurhexafluoride & \callchemfigsymbol[base.base]{sulfurhexafluoride_pseudo_3D_stereo.tex} \\
  Trifluoromethyl-sulfurpentafluoride & \callchemfigsymbol[base.base]{trifluoromethylsulfurpentafluoride_pseudo_3D_stereo.tex} \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

#### A mixing of finer surrounding spaces and not touching the contents of `chemfig` objects

Main changes:
 - new `tikz` option `enlarge bounding box by`
 - `\defaultaddspace` is used to specify the extra vertical spaces around every `\callchemfigsymbol`
 - use `\\` instead of `\\[\defaultaddspace]` inside `tabular`

```
\documentclass[border=6pt,active]{standalone}%
\usepackage{booktabs}%
%\usepackage{miscchemsym}%
\usepackage{chemfig}%
\usepackage{filecontents}%
\usepackage{tikz}%
\usepackage{catchfile}%

\tikzset{
  % #1 = left, #2 = lower, #3 = right, #4 = upper
  enlarge bounding box by/.style n args={4}{
    execute at end picture={
      \path ([shift={(-#1, -#2)}]current bounding box.south west) --
            ([shift={(#3, #4)}]current bounding box.north east);
    }
  }
}

% chemfigdo
\newcommand{\chemfigdo}[2]{\chemfig[#2]{#1}}%

% chemfiginput
\newcommand{\chemfiginput}[2][]{%
  \CatchFileDef{\chemfiginputtemp}{#2}{\csname CF_sanitizecatcode\endcsname}%
  \expandafter\chemfigdo\expandafter{\chemfiginputtemp}{#1}%
}%

% create new command for tikzpicture call
\newcommand\callchemfigsymbol[1]{%
  \chemfiginput[
      atom style={scale=\chemfigscale},
      atom sep=\chemfigatomsep,
      chemfig style={
        enlarge bounding box by={0pt}{\defaultaddspace}{0pt}{\defaultaddspace},
        baseline=(current bounding box.center),
        color=\chemfigcolor,
        line width=\chemfiglinewidth
      }
    ]{#1}%
}

% define the atom sep
\newlength{\chemfigatomsep}%
\setlength{\chemfigatomsep}{2.75em}%

% define the line width
\newlength{\chemfiglinewidth}%
\setlength{\chemfiglinewidth}{0.75pt}%

% define the scale
\def\chemfigscale{0.8}

% define the color
\def\chemfigcolor{red!40!black}

% define separation length
\setlength{\defaultaddspace}{3pt}


\begin{document}

%% To save space, three filecontents environments are ignored

\begin{tabular}{cc}
  \toprule
  \textbf{Compound name} & \textbf{Structure} \\
  \midrule
  Methane & \callchemfigsymbol{methane_pseudo_3D_stereo.tex} \\
  Sulfurhexafluoride & \callchemfigsymbol{sulfurhexafluoride_pseudo_3D_stereo.tex} \\
  Trifluoromethyl-sulfurpentafluoride & \callchemfigsymbol{trifluoromethylsulfurpentafluoride_pseudo_3D_stereo.tex} \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

#### PS

Since LaTeX2e version 2019-10-01, the utility of `filecontents` package has been merged in the LaTeX2e format, so there is no need to load `filecontents` package.

Comment: Legend.  When I try to externalize the setup commands, I'm getting: `! Package pgf Error: No shape named base is known`

Comment: The moment that I strip away the invocations of `filecontents` and instead point the `\callchemfigsymbol{}` commands to absolute file paths (e.g. `C:/library/chemfig/<symbol file name>.tex`) I receive the above error.

Comment: @JohnChris There are three `@{base}` added to contents of `filecontents` env.

Comment: Thank you.  A solution where the `chemfig` object must be modified is not ideal.  Consider a large library of `chemfig` symbols which are generated from `.mol` or `.sdf` files automatically.  Also consider that the table described in this post may be long and will be populated with a variety of different compounds / changed and re-generated frequently.  The requirement for a user to go into the `chemfig` object and manually select the `base` is too time consuming / adds complexity to the workflow.  Can we think of alternatives?

Comment: @JohnChris I have appended a new solution variant to the end of my answer, in which  vertical spacing is finer and `chemfig` objects is not touched.